# What is a strategy for creating C# property classes / returning specific properties for different types?

Tags: c#, asp.net, properties

In a forthcoming application, there will be several supplier types which can include hotels, restaurants, transportation services, meeting venues.

In planning the data model, I was thinking of having one table with most of the common properties between all types.  Displaying/selecting specific properties based on the supplier type would be determined by its respective supplier type class which would contain a list of which properties to return for that supplier.

In cases where a supplier has say, "meeting spaces", a foreign key relationship will be created to a 1..* table containing those properties.

It's been a while since I have done this so I would like a refresher on how to accomplish this in C#, if in fact this is a good strategy, rather than creating separate tables for each supplier type.  An update on proper terminology would be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to use Entity Framework, there are 2 different ways to implement model mapping to SQL tables when you have inheritance:

### [Table per Type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617#2.5)

> In the TPT mapping scenario, all types are mapped to individual
>   tables. Properties that belong solely to a base type or derived type
>   are stored in a table that maps to that type. Tables that map to
>   derived types also store a foreign key that joins the derived table
>   with the base table.

### [Table per Concrete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617#2.6)

> In the TPC mapping scenario, all non-abstract types in the hierarchy
>   are mapped to individual tables. The tables that map to the derived
>   classes have no relationship to the table that maps to the base class
>   in the database. All properties of a class, including inherited
>   properties, are mapped to columns of the corresponding table.

---

Here is a great [article](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-inheritance-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) to start. **Even if you are not going to use EF**, it's a good reading for you. It will give you some ideas of how to implement tables and models structure.

Comment: I typically approach my data modeling from a database-first perspective.  I am still not sure if I want to go with EF, due to the results latency issues.  

In assuming a model with Table-per-Hierarchy inheritance I can see how this will work.  However, how would this handle a situation where some suppliers have some of the same shared properties, like where a restaurant and hotel both have meeting spaces?

Comment: @ElHaix I don't recommend you to use TPH. Though doesn't matter if you go or not to go with EF, one of listed approaches should work for you data in terms of db design.

Comment: What are some of the issues you see with using TPH - why not use it?  What is your suggestion and why?

Comment: I just think that with the other approaches you would get a more clear data structure.